# Querying SQL Server 2005 for certain XML values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, select, case-expression

I am trying to query XML columns in SQL Server 2005

I have a really long string which is stored in a column and it is XML. I want to check if the visibility of a certain item is set to true or not.

Any idea on how to do this?

I can't post the string that has all the XML because this stack editor doesn't like the code.

Thanks

I have attached a picture showing my select statement and the results, you can see from the case expressions what I am trying to do.

[image]

Problem is the settings column shows the name of the column but I want to see if the visibility of that column e.g. `(colFirstChoiceVendorPaymentTerms)` is set to true or not...

Comment: at least send the structure and data you want to filter

Comment: `declare @x xml
set @x=''
select @x.exist('true()') ` ???

Comment: column that stores XML is the settings column...

Comment: <property name="Visible">true</property>

Comment: and where can we find visibility?

Comment: @evhen14 <property name="Item24" isnull="true" iskey="true"> <property name="Visible">true</property> <property name="SortMode">Value</property> <property name="VisibleIndex">6</property> <property name="Width">32</property> <property name="Name">colFirstChoiceVendorPaymentTerms</property> </property>

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, just simply highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question depends heavily on xml schema you're using. For example, if you're using attributes xml like this:

```
'<Item ID="1" Visibility="1" />'
```

You can filter items with this query:

```
select *
from temp
where data.exist('Item[@Visibility = "1"]') = 1
```

See this on **<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07848/1)</kbd>**

It's hard to answer more precise until we don't have exact schema of your xml.

---

#### update

So it looks like you have DevExpress settings xml stored inside your db. So if your simplified xml is like this:

```
<XtraSerializer version="1.0" application="View">
  <property name="Columns" iskey="true" value="9">
    <property name="colFirstChoiceVendorPaymentTerms" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="Visible">true</property>
    </property>
    <property name="colSecondChoiceVendorPaymentTerms" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="Visible">false</property>
    </property>
  </property>
</XtraSerializer>
```

Then you can query it like:

```
select
data.value('(XtraSerializer/property/property[@name="colFirstChoiceVendorPaymentTerms"]/property[@name="Visible"])[1]', 'bit') as first,

data.value('(XtraSerializer/property/property[@name="colSecondChoiceVendorPaymentTerms"]/property[@name="Visible"])[1]', 'bit') as second
from temp
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc039/1)</kbd>**

---

#### update 2

if your data type is text/varchar, try this:

```
select
    c.data_xml.value('(XtraSerializer/property/property[@name="colFirstChoiceVendorPaymentTerms"]/property[@name="Visible"])[1]', 'bit') as first,
    c.data_xml.value('(XtraSerializer/property/property[@name="colSecondChoiceVendorPaymentTerms"]/property[@name="Visible"])[1]', 'bit') as second
from temp as t
    outer apply (select cast(t.data as xml) as data_xml) as c
```

Comment: <property name="Item24" isnull="true" iskey="true">        
<property name="Visible">true</property>        
<property name="SortMode">Value</property>        
<property name="VisibleIndex">6</property>        
<property name="Width">32</property>        
<property name="Name">colFirstChoiceVendorPaymentTerms</property>      </property>

Comment: this is part of the XML. the property name is colFirstChoiceVendorPaymentTerms, im checking if the visibility is set to true or not.. in this case it is true

Comment: thank you for your help but how would i add this to my case statement?

Comment: why do you need case statement? I think you just need 1/0 for columns first/second/third

Comment: i seem to be getting errors because i am casting the column names from a table on a different server. 

data.value = data is the column name i assume?

Comment: yes i see, but it throws error: Msg 258, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Cannot call methods on text.

Comment: ok i have uploaded the XML here: txt.do/dev1 you will see that the visibility for colFirstChoiceVendorPaymentTerms and colSecondChoiceVendorPaymentTerms is set to true. but there is no visibility for colThirdChoiceVendorPaymentTerms. this is what i want to check. if visibility is there or not. thank you again for your help.

Comment: my last query should do it, try it on your db

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(data as XML).exist('//XtraSerializer//property[@name="colFirstChoiceVendorPaymentTerms"]/property[@name=''Visible'' and text()=''true'']') as col1,
  CAST(data as XML).exist('//XtraSerializer//property[@name="colSecondChoiceVendorPaymentTerms"]/property[@name=''Visible'' and text()=''true'']') as col2
  FROM TBL
```

Comment: thanks but this returns a lot of data, i need the result to be specific to a column in the XML

Comment: is it possible to get the columns to say 1 for true and 0 for false?

Comment: edited once again, but without XML it's hard to help, I don't have data to test it.